# Avoid UI locking/freezing when assigning datasource?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using MVP pattern, so I have a View that has almost no logic in it and a Presenter that knows how to react to the user's interactions with the view. 
Everytime I need to get data from a service or such my code does so asynchronously, the problem I'm having is that lets say I get 10,000 items that need to be databound to a Grid, when I assign those (marshalling them through the UI thread) my UI locks for short periods of time (because of the Grid control/CurrencyManager locking the thread I think)

Does anybody know possible ways to avoid this?

I've tried assigning the data in incremental chunks with a timer, but still ends making the UI freeze randomly

Cheers

Comment: why on earth are you doing this: "lets say I get 10,000 items that need to be databound to a Grid," - have you heard of paging? 500 items at a time is more than enough for 99% of apps

Comment: Its a rich client, why should I page? do you see paging in excel?

Comment: @Sebastian Piu: consider this: what is a grid usually used for? to display the results of a search. Narrow the search up front. No user wants to read 10,000 items nor is it possible in any workable time frame.

Comment: Its a grid and its a rich client. the grid has client side filters that can be used to reduce the data. Users need to view, compare, sort things in the grid that might be different without moving from page to page and without having to go back and forth to the DB

Comment: @Sebastian Piu: I was under the impression that's what a computer was for, comparing large numbers of items!

Comment: My god, you don't give up don't you? Yes, maybe is a best idea to implement AI and let that troubleshoot what my users need to do.

Comment: @Sebastian Piu: you obviously know best. Good luck with that.

Comment: Yes, Excel pages. It also has some pretty extreme optimizations at work, completely unnecessary in a modern app and hardly worth the hassle. For example, the original file format saved everything in binary format, so it was simply a matter of blitting a range of bytes from the disk to memory. It didn't have to access a database or any other such thing.

Comment: @Sebastian Piu Paging @Mitch Wheat is talking is the only solution to go, you can achieve this by virtual mode ( depend on the grid you use can change a little but the concept is the same). No user will read 10000 record in a grid.

Comment: I already went through the process of trying to convince the users not to have it that way, but that is what they want, i just need to get it working the best possible. It works quite well with a limit around 10,000, the only thing I want to polish is the process of loading the data (now i'm doing it 500 at a time) but there are minor freezes that I'd like to get rid of, once data is loaded everything works just fine.. I'll see how it goes with the VirtualMode in the grid

Comment: I just answered that way to Mitch because I made a polite question and instead of just trying to help or know why I have to do it in a certain way he just started ranting/being sarcastic

Comment: @Sebastian Piu: I refute that remark of yours. I was trying to suggest you do not display 10,000 results in a grid.

Comment: @Sebastian Piu: for the record I was not ranting at any point. I may have been sarcastic; I often am.

Comment: @Mitch ok, no problem then. I guess that what I want to do is to page in some sort of way, but not in a traditional 'go to next page' way (which is what I thought when I read your comment). I just need to load the data in a more efficient way than just all at once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use some sort of [virtual data mod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode.aspx)e for your grid. This will remove such kind of problem definitively.

Answer (score 3):

You need to download the data from the server in chunks on a background thread then append them to a client side collection object.  If that collection object implements [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged.aspx) then the grid should update automatically.  You can get this with [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx), or with [Bindable Linq](http://bindablelinq.codeplex.com/) which may be a better choice.

The problem you will run into is that you have a grid re-drawing 10,000 items over and over again.  This is generally not that good of a solution but it can work if you get a grid with UI Virtualization.  For example I use the [Telerik GridView](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/gridview.aspx) control and I have had good results with around 5000 records.

Having tried to answer your question directly, let me give you some advice that may lead you in a better direction.  Direct query of 10,000 items over the network isn't going to be blazing fast no matter how cool your grid control is.  You may want to consider using a service bus to communicate async to the server and store a copy of the data in a local database.  I am working on a project that will use [Rhino Service Bus to make a smart client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796225.aspx) that can work even if the network connection goes down for a short time.  The service bus approach to smart client development should make your UI locking pains go away and make your app more stable and resilient to network traffic.

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm not having problems with the network as I'm already retrieving the data in chunks and that happens in a different thread. My only problem is when sending those to the Grid and repainting as you mentioned afterwards. I'll check the Virtual mode of the grid component I'm using at the moment (infragistics) and see how that goes. Thanks!